# which java framework or lib use to check data in db or cache first

Tags: java, database, spring, caching

I have a java application. My app makes a call to an external service, then store the data into the database. I want to make it check record in db first, and if not found, make a call to an external service then. I don't want to use hand-made solution for this, I hope there is a library or framework which can do it. I use spring and hibernate 4. What can I do to do that as more gracefully as it possible?

Comment: So, what you want is if(exist) then dosomthing?

Comment: I don't think so there are any library to do that. This is very easy task to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have tight constraints on the number of calls you can make to the external system, you might want to consider executing both calls at the same time and using whichever responds first.

```
// Create futures for the two tasks to run concurrently
CompletableFuture<MyObject> checkCache = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> cache.lookup(key));
CompletableFuture<MyObject> callExternal = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> externalService.lookup(key));
// run the two operations, and react to the first to complete
checkCache.applyToEither(callExternal, 
                         result -> {
                             cache.store(key, result);
                             return result;
                         })
           .applyTo(result -> // do something with the returned value);
```

This is using Java 8, but you can use Guava, etc, if you're using an earlier version of Java.